# How do you pronounce the following $x \mathbin{\hat{\circ}} y$?

Tags: numerical-methods, notation, terminology

I was reading about "error analysis", in particular about rounding errors in the floating point operations representing the real operations such as multiplication or division.

There was the following:

> $$x \mathbin{\hat{\circ}} y = (x \circ y)(1 + \epsilon)$$
>
> for an $\epsilon = \epsilon(x, y)$ with $|\epsilon| \leq eps$.

Is there some kind of conventional way for mathematicians to pronounce $x \mathbin{\hat{\circ}} y$? I would say "x circle hat y" or "x approximated floating point operation y", but as you may have noticed I'm not a native English speaker.

Second and maybe more important question. What does the notation $\epsilon = \epsilon(x, y)$ actually mean?

Comment: For the second question, they are just saying that exactly what $\epsilon$ is in a specific situation depends on $x$ and $y$. In other words, instead of being a constant $\epsilon$, it's a _function_ $\epsilon(x,y)$. They just don't write that out in the main expression, probably to make it easier to read.

Comment: Perhaps. In the end, it's just a specification saying "... and when we say $\epsilon$, we really mean $\epsilon(x,y)$." Or perhaps "where $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon(x,y)$ mean the same thing."